# Sort elements in each row of a 3-d matrix in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to sort the elements in each row of a 3-d matrix `A` in Matlab. This matrix has dimension `(m)x(n)x(g)`. `g` is set equal to `3`. The order should be done in ascending order, firstly wrto `A(:,:,1)`, then `A(:,:,2)` and finally `A(:,:,3)`.

For example:

```
A(:,:,1)=[3 1 1; 4 5 6; 0 0 0; 1 1 1];
A(:,:,2)=[3 3 4; 1 4 0; 0 1 0; 2 1 7];
A(:,:,3)=[6 7 9; 6 6 0; 6 5 0; 0 0 0];

%Step 1: Order wrto A(:,:,1)
A(:,:,1)=[1 1 3; 4 5 6; 0 0 0; 1 1 1];
A(:,:,2)=[3 4 3; 1 4 0; 0 1 0; 2 1 7];
A(:,:,3)=[7 9 6; 6 6 0; 6 5 0; 0 0 0];

%Step 2: Within the order in Step 1, order wrto A(:,:,2)
A(:,:,1)=[1 1 3; 4 5 6; 0 0 0; 1 1 1];
A(:,:,2)=[3 4 3; 1 4 0; 0 0 1; 1 2 7];
A(:,:,3)=[7 9 6; 6 6 0; 6 0 5; 0 0 0];

%Step 3: Within the order in Step 1 and 2, order wrto A(:,:,3)
A(:,:,1)=[1 1 3; 4 5 6; 0 0 0; 1 1 1];
A(:,:,2)=[3 4 3; 1 4 0; 0 0 1; 1 2 7];
A(:,:,3)=[7 9 6; 6 6 0; 0 6 5; 0 0 0];
```

Comment: are there any specifications on m and n with regards to the sorting operation? Or you are only sorting the 3rd Dimension independently of m and n?

Comment: I'm not sure I got your point. In the example abive m=4, n=3. g is always set equal to 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply [`sortrows`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) to each *horizontal slice* of `A`, *seen from above* (so that the third dimension becomes the "rows" in "`sort`*`rows`*"):

```
B = NaN(size(A));
for n = 1:size(A,1),
    B(n,:,:) = sortrows(squeeze(A(n,:,:)));
end
```

Comment: Had hard time figuring out how OP got to the expected o/p, definitely great mentalist skills ;)

Comment: Thanks, @Divakar! This wasn't the clearest of questions, indeed